# In Python why is [2] less than (1,)?

Tags: python

### BACKGROUND

I've been trying to work out why my AI has been making some crazy moves and I traced the problem back to the following behaviour when using Python 2.7.2

```
>>> print [2]>[1]
True
>>> print (2,)>(1,)
True
>>> print [2]>(1,)
False                 (WHY?)

>>> print [2]<[1]
False
>>> print (2,)<(1,)
False
>>> print [2]<(1,)
True                  (WHY?)
```

It seems to behave as if lists are always less than tuples.

This is not what I expected from the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in)

> Tuples and lists are compared lexicographically using comparison of
>   corresponding elements. This means that to compare equal, each element
>   must compare equal and the two sequences must be of the same type and
>   have the same length.
>
> If not equal, the sequences are ordered the same as their first
>   differing elements. For example, cmp([1,2,x], [1,2,y]) returns the
>   same as cmp(x,y). If the corresponding element does not exist, the
>   shorter sequence is ordered first (for example, [1,2] < [1,2,3]).

### QUESTION

What is going on here?  Am I allowed to compare tuples and lists - or perhaps am I only allowed to compare the same type with itself?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17284326

Answer (score 22, accepted):

They're not the same type.

> each element must compare equal and **the two sequences must be of the same type** and have the same length

So the comparison is being performed based on type, not on actual data stored in the sequences.  On python3.x, this comparison raises a `TypeError`:

```
Python 3.2 (r32:88445, May 11 2011, 09:23:22) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> [2] > (1,)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: list() > tuple()
```

Comment: Ah, simple failure to read on my part again I see.  Many thanks!  I love that in Python 3 I wouldn't be able to make this mistake.  I am now very tempted to update at last!

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz -- For what it's worth, that's for the sequences to compare equal.  The next paragraph which deals more with rich comparisons doesn't make it quite as clear that they need to be the same type.

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz -- FWIW, I thought that the wording there was ambiguous enough to warrant writing an email to docs@python.org in order to try to improve the docs.

Answer (score 25):

Sequences are not coerced when comparing, hence their type name is compared instead.

```
>>> 'list' < 'tuple'
True
```

Comment: Where is this behavior specified?

Comment: For what it's worth, python does specify that the comparison is done by type, but it doesn't specify that types compare by their names.  I believe this is the behavior in Cpython, but other implementations may give different results.

Comment: @MattBall At the bottom of [section 5.3](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons): **CPython implementation detail**: Objects of different types except numbers are ordered by their type names; objects of the same types that don’t support proper comparison are ordered by their address.

Comment: The reason is that "Objects of different types, except different numeric types and different string types, never compare equal; such objects are ordered consistently but arbitrarily (so that sorting a heterogeneous array yields a consistent result)". On that basis, using type name is reasonable enough. I'd love to see a `__future__` option to enable 3.x-style comparisons.

Comment: @Marcin -- they're probably waiting until python2.8 to put that one in there ;-)

Comment: @mgilson I reckon 2.8 will happen after 2.7.19 or so. Let's hope we get it before then.

Comment: @Marcin -- doubtful.  I think they're pretty set on having python2.7 be the last of the python2.x series.  The only way that a python2.8 is coming out is if somebody takes the python2.7 source code and decides to fork it and create their own language "extension" from it -- And I'm not even sure if there are legal ramifications to that ... (e.g. I doubt they could call it python2.8)

Comment: @mgilson I jest slightly. However, I don't think python 2 is going to naturally die out as quickly at the python foundation thinks. If it's going long enough to need that many maintenance releases, they may just capitulate and call a subsequent release 2.8.